# Remove the values from array1 by referring to array2

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have two arrays and I want to remove the values from array1 by referring to array2. The expected result is ["b", "c",];

```js
array1 = ["aa", "bb", "b", "c",];

array2 = [{key: "a", value: "A"}, {key: "b", value: "B"}, {key: "c", value: "C"}, {key: "d", value: "D"}];
```

I have tried with filter, but it returns `[{key: "b", value: "B"}, {key: "c", value: "C"}]`

```js
array2.filter((item) => {return array1.includes(item.key)})
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
array1 = ["aa", "bb", "b", "c",];
array2 = [{key: "a", value: "A"}, {key: "b", value: "B"}, {key: "c", value: "C"}, {key: "d", value: "D"}]; 
array3 = array2.map((item) => (item.key))

remainingItems = array1.filter((item) => array3.includes(item))
```

The issue with the code you posted is that you're referring to the wrong variables.

```
// array2 shouldn't be used as you're expecting values from array1
array2.filter((item) => {return array1.includes(item.key)})

// inefficient with repeating maps of array2 but looks closer to your code.
array1.filter((item) => { return array2.map((item) => (item.key)).includes(item) })
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this.

```js
const array1 = ["aa", "bb", "b", "c",];

const array2 = [{key: "a", value: "A"}, {key: "b", value: "B"}, {key: "c", value: "C"}, {key: "d", value: "D"}];


const result = array1.filter(a => array2.map(({key}) => key).includes(a))

console.log(result)
```

As @Nick Parsons noted it probably be more efficent using `some` like this

```js
const array1 = ["aa", "bb", "b", "c",];

const array2 = [{key: "a", value: "A"}, {key: "b", value: "B"}, {key: "c", value: "C"}, {key: "d", value: "D"}];


const result = array1.filter(a => array2.some(({key}) => key === a))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Using `.some()` seems like it would be more appropriate here instead of using `.map()` + `.includes()`, which involves doing two iterations of `array2` for each element you loop over in `array1`, with `.some()`, you can change that to only do 1 iteration of `array2` instead of 2. You could also even move the `.map()` outside of the `.filter()` (similar to Amat's answer), but then put the results into a Set and use `.has()` on the set within the `.filter()` callback (this is only worth doing if `array2` is large)

Comment: @NickParsons Do forgive me for asking as I don't know what that would look like, but can you post a snippet for what you've just described?

Comment: @Amats I updated my answer using `some`. Great comment Nick Parsons! I agree with you but I think that for an array of 4 elements it doesn't really make any difference

Comment: @Amats R4ncid's update answer shows an approach with `.some()`. The other option I mentioned also was to use a `Set`, which would look something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6n59zcpo/), but is only be useful when `array2` is large.